# ffmpeg capture of 1366 x 768 desktop is skewed but FaceTime cam capture is fine

Tags: screen-capture

Per the [ffmpeg Capture/Desktop instructions](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#OSX) using [avfoundation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation) to access input devices the FaceTime camera captures look fine:
`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0:none" facetime_cam.mov`
...but using
`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:none" screen.mov`
...the desktop looks like this:

[image]

How can I use ffmpeg to capture my desktop?

ffmpeg 3.2.2
macOS 10.12.3

-------------------------UPDATE:
the [folks @ ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6111) suggested I "specify another pixel format" - so, I'll try and figure out how to do that. I am confused as to why the desktop looks terrible and the FaceTime camera looks "normal" without any specific parameters tho?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using QuickTime to do it instead? It's not an answer, but a possible workaround.

Comment: @NoahL whatTheWHAT?? swEEt! How long has this been a thing??? ...I guess since 2012: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH5882?locale=en_US Heh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [FFmpeg's bug tracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/5654), I was able to ascertain that the source of the problem is specific to the default resolution of the Mac AirBook: 1366 x 768.

> The linesize ... was 1376 ... but
>   the buffer size was for a linesize of 1366.

After switching the AirBooks Built-In Display resolution, I am able to successfully capture a recognizable desktop movie:

[image]

To resolve this problem requires implementing [a patch](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/attachment/ticket/5654/fix-5654.patch) which I do not know how to do yet.